# Generate matrix from uneven vectors, matching presence and absence as 0 or 1

Tags: r

I'm looking to combine different sized vectors. I'd like to list values as either row or column names, and if present in any one of these vectors, will be set to 1. If absent in any one of these vectors, will be set to 0.
I can have upwards of 20 vectors, containing a string of upwards of 300 values
Apologies if my terminology is incorrect, I'm relatively new to R!

An example of my data:

```
v1 =  "ASV581" "ASV547"  "ASV434" "ASV378"  "ASV7" "ASV1478" "ASV676" "ASV361" "ASV142"  "ASV92"   "ASV16" "ASV2"  

v2 = "ASV15" "ASV7" "ASV5" "ASV2" "ASV676" "ASV581" "ASV522" "ASV361"

v3 = "ASV1"  "ASV7"  "ASV3"  "ASV15  "ASV2" "ASV38" "ASV28  "ASV22" "ASV5"  "ASV346""ASV208" "ASV139"  "ASV13" "ASV919" "ASV676"  

v4 = "ASV15" "ASV7"  "ASV5"  "ASV2" "ASV208" "ASV139" "ASV361" "ASV142"
```

So far I've combined all vectors and generated a unique list

```
x <- c(v1, v2, v3, v4)
ASVitems <- unique(x)
```

But I seem to be having problems generating the matrix and get setting conditions for presence or absence.

Here is an example of what I would like to have:

```
      [v1]   [v2]   [v3]   [v4]   ...
ASV2   1      1      1      1
ASV3   0      0      1      0
ASV5   0      1      1      0
ASV7   1      1      1      1
...
```

Thanks so much!
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can put your uneven vectors into a named list:

```
ASVitems <- list(v1 = v1, v2 = v2, v3 = v3, v4 = v4)
```

The result looks like this:

```
$v1
 [1] "ASV581"  "ASV547"  "ASV434"  "ASV378"  "ASV7"    "ASV1478" "ASV676"  "ASV361"  "ASV142"  "ASV92"   "ASV16"   "ASV2"   

$v2
[1] "ASV15"  "ASV7"   "ASV5"   "ASV2"   "ASV676" "ASV581" "ASV522" "ASV361"

$v3
 [1] "ASV1"   "ASV7"   "ASV3"   "ASV15"  "ASV2"   "ASV38"  "ASV28"  "ASV22"  "ASV5"   "ASV346" "ASV208" "ASV139" "ASV13"  "ASV919" "ASV676"

$v4
[1] "ASV15"  "ASV7"   "ASV5"   "ASV2"   "ASV208" "ASV139" "ASV361" "ASV142"
```

Then you can put all of the `unique` ASV character values into a long vector:

```
Allitems <- unique(unlist(ASVitems))
```

That looks like this:

```
 [1] "ASV581"  "ASV547"  "ASV434"  "ASV378"  "ASV7"    "ASV1478" "ASV676"  "ASV361"  "ASV142"  "ASV92"   "ASV16"   "ASV2"    "ASV15"   "ASV5"   
[15] "ASV522"  "ASV1"    "ASV3"    "ASV38"   "ASV28"   "ASV22"   "ASV346"  "ASV208"  "ASV139"  "ASV13"   "ASV919"
```

Finally, create a matrix, using `sapply` across each of the ASV vectors in `ASVitems`, and checking which of `Allitems` is contained within it. You can set the row and column names accordingly. The final step converts to a data.frame, and sorts by the numeric value contained in ASVXXX.

```
mat <- +sapply(ASVitems, `%in%`, x = Allitems)
rownames(mat) <- Allitems
colnames(mat) <- names(ASVitems)
data.frame(mat)[order(as.numeric(gsub("ASV", "", Allitems))),]
```

**Output**

```
        v1 v2 v3 v4
ASV1     0  0  1  0
ASV2     1  1  1  1
ASV3     0  0  1  0
ASV5     0  1  1  1
ASV7     1  1  1  1
ASV13    0  0  1  0
ASV15    0  1  1  1
ASV16    1  0  0  0
ASV22    0  0  1  0
ASV28    0  0  1  0
ASV38    0  0  1  0
ASV92    1  0  0  0
ASV139   0  0  1  1
ASV142   1  0  0  1
ASV208   0  0  1  1
ASV346   0  0  1  0
ASV361   1  1  0  1
ASV378   1  0  0  0
ASV434   1  0  0  0
ASV522   0  1  0  0
ASV547   1  0  0  0
ASV581   1  1  0  0
ASV676   1  1  1  0
ASV919   0  0  1  0
ASV1478  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you Ben! That's exactly what I was looking for! Very much appreciated :)